# react webpack build tool for multiple brand

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I am using react boilerplate for my project. I am wondering how can I use the same codebase for multiple brand? Thing is like that :

- multiple brand might have multiple color, different text, and the
  functionality might be different.
- The scenario might be like this: the main project contains component 
  A,B,C . Company X has a new component which is coponent D and also
  company X has modified component A with some new functionality.
- I want to build company X project by using the default package.json
  all dependencis in addition component D and modified component A.

  How to achieve this?